# SQL Query Source Control

Tags: sql, github

Does anyone have a good method for doing source control against SQL Queries.  I am not concerned with the database itself but rather just the SQL queries.

Currently I store them in a folder on my local machine and intend to just point GITHUB at that folder.  However, it would be ideal if there is a solution that integrates into SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The one that I use is [RedGate's Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=sqlsourcecontrol&gclid=CPvSmKPUq70CFcJZ2wodKr0AiQ), this product integrates directly in to SQL Server Management Studio. Unfortunately, this is not a free product.

Another option with a trial version (55 days)
[Agent SVN - SCC Subversion Plug-in](http://www.zeusedit.com/agent/ssms/ms_ssms.html)